# Family Link blocks the manager parent

Tags: google-play, parental-control

I have set up a family group of Google accounts and installed Google's Family Link app on my smartphone to manage my children's tablet.
I have noticed that I can no longer get results nor install or update many apps from Google's play store.

When I search I get a message of something like "a parental control blocks this app" and when I try to access the app via a link I cannot install it with a message of "this app is not compatible with the device"